# Vitamio bundle scratch voice

Tags: android, m3u8, vitamio

I am using vitamio library for streaming m3u8 format. I hav written these codes. It is running.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private Button baslat;
private Button durdur;
private VideoView videoView;
private String httpLiveUrl = "http://strm-l.glb.mncdn.net/kaybedenlerkulubu/live/playlist.m3u8";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    this.setTitle("Standart FM");



    baslat = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonBasla);
    durdur = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonDurdur);
    videoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.VideoView);

    baslat.setEnabled(true);
    durdur.setEnabled(true);

    if (!io.vov.vitamio.LibsChecker.checkVitamioLibs(this))
        return;

    videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(httpLiveUrl));

    baslat.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(getApplicationContext());
            videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
            //videoView.requestFocus();
            videoView.start();
        }
    });

    durdur.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            durdur.setEnabled(false);
            // Buraya stream i durdurma yazılacak
        }
    });

}
```

Bu when i clicked to baslat button I heard only scratch voice. Here is my logcat occcurs.

```
07-22 09:00:55.031: D/Vitamio[Player](539): 106977
07-22 09:00:55.031: I/Vitamio[Player](539): META AUDIO: 0. 106977, META SUBTITLE: 
07-22 09:00:55.031: D/Vitamio[Player](539): FIND CODEC_ID 86018
07-22 09:00:55.031: I/Vitamio[Player](539): OOPS: ONLY 1
07-22 09:00:55.081: D/Vitamio[Player](539): OPEN CODEC aac
07-22 09:00:55.081: I/Vitamio[Player](539): OPEN STREAM AUDIO BEGIN
07-22 09:00:55.081: I/Vitamio[Player](539): Copyright (c) VOV IO (http://vov.io).
07-22 09:00:55.081: I/Vitamio[Player](539): THIS SOFTWARE (Vitamio) IS WORK OF VOV IO      (http://vov.io)
07-22 09:00:55.091: I/Vitamio[Player](539): Application package name:     com.applogist.standartfmproject
07-22 09:00:55.091: I/Vitamio[Player](539): 2, 44100, 0
07-22 09:00:55.100: I/Vitamio[Player](539): OPEN STREAM AUDIO END
07-22 09:00:55.100: D/Vitamio[Player](539): CLEAN START
07-22 09:00:55.100: D/Vitamio[Player](539): prepared
07-22 09:00:55.111: D/Vitamio(539): onPrepared
07-22 09:00:55.111: D/Vitamio[Player](539): start
07-22 09:00:55.130: D/Vitamio[Player](539): THREAD AUDIO_DECODE START
07-22 09:00:55.141: D/Vitamio[Player](539): CLEAN END
07-22 09:00:55.141: I/Vitamio[Player](539): THREAD PREPARE DETTACHED
07-22 09:00:55.151: D/Vitamio[Player](539): THREAD AUDIO_OUTPUT START
07-22 09:00:55.151: I/Vitamio[Player](539): THREAD PREPARE END
07-22 09:00:55.161: D/Vitamio[Player](539): THREAD DEMUX START
07-22 09:00:55.181: I/Vitamio(539): Info (701, 0)
07-22 09:00:55.181: D/Vitamio(539): onInfo: (701, 0)
07-22 09:00:55.181: D/Vitamio[Player](539): stop
07-22 09:00:55.191: I/Vitamio(539): Info (901, 0)
07-22 09:00:55.191: D/Vitamio(539): onInfo: (901, 0)
07-22 09:01:05.124: I/Vitamio(539): Info (901, 36)
07-22 09:01:05.124: D/Vitamio(539): onInfo: (901, 36)
```

I have tried on 2.3 and 4.0 device. But i heard the same voice. Scratch. What can i do for solvinf this problem?

Comment: Post your stacktrace so we can see what error is occuring

Comment: I would post all of that within your question not in commments or start another question about it.  Also delete all those comments with the stacktrace.